# How to obscure the numbers in the textarea field

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, preg-replace

I have using cakephp and I want to obscure all numbers which is more than six digits.

something like this

```
 $string = "My id number is 77765444 in Sales dept.";

 becomes 

 $string = "My id number is XXXXXXXX in Sales dept."
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous):

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\d{6,}/', function($match) { return str_repeat('X', strlen($match[0])); }, $string);
```

The anonymous function is used to replace each occurrence of six or more consecutive digits by the same amount of `X`. If your PHP version does not support anonymous functions (available since 5.3), use a normal function instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\d/', 'X', "My id number is 77765444 in Sales dept.");
```

Comment: No, this will simply convert all digits to X, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: You mean 1) what if the number is not more than 6 digits and 2) what if there are situations that numbers occur multiple times, such as in `"For some reason there are 2 ID numbers 77765444 in Sales dept."`